# OST on My Hero Academia season 2 episode 3 around 12:05-12:45

Tags: music, my-hero-academia

On *My Hero Academia* season 2 episode 3 from about 12:05 to about 12:45 and maybe longer, there's an OST playing in the background that I can't seem to track down and I could use some help.

What's that song?

Answer (score 0):

Kyōi To No Kōbō / Offense And Defense Of A Threat

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bwtMpGBBq9I